# Image displaying sideways

Tags: css, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave to upload an image. The image uploads fine. But any vertical image (only vertical images) displays sideways. How can I fix this?

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="profile_picture">
            <%= image_tag @user.attachment.url %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the image tag turns into:

```
<img src="/uploads/user/attachment/23/CIMG6610.JPG" alt="Cimg6610">
```

CSS:

```
.profile_picture {
    max-width: 100%;
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

if I look at the upload directly in the browser "localhost:3000/uploads/user/attachment/23/CIMG6610.JPG" it displays correctly

Comment: Can you add a js fiddle, or at least a screenshot?

Comment: So portraight images (taller than they are wide) are displaying as landscape images (wider than they are tall)?

Is this just visually (i.e. the image is being stretched) or is the image being physically altered (rotated on upload). Are you sure the original is what you think it is?

Comment: Correct just portrait images are displaying sideways. The image is physically being turned. I dont think it's an issue with upload because if I look directly at the image URL the image displays fine. @JohnDevelops

Comment: It seems that this could be an issue with how photos ratio/rotation is defined, i.e. devices flagging an image as portrait rather than saving it as such, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/9wqJ-kn9c-U However im not 100% sure as this would also effect directly viewing the image?

Comment: @JohnDevelops I guess it was an issue with upload as adding the "img.auto_orient" fixed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: :) Add the answer in the Answer box below to help others who may find this thread

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be an issue with the upload. Adding this to my Uploader fixed the issue.

```
  process :auto_orient

  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.auto_orient
    end
  end
```

Thanks @JohnDevelops