# Images appearing as portrait Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I was following these tutorials for the Carrierwave gem: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078003/image-displaying-sideways) and [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/9wqJ-kn9c-U). I upload images, and they're automatically rotated to portrait form. Now, I tried the solution in the tutorials, and it didn't work for me. I was wondering if anyone had ideas on how to fix it.

Here's image_uploader.rb:

```
process :auto_orient
process :resize_to_fit => [720, 720]

def auto_orient
  manipulate! do |img|
    img = img.auto_orient
  end
end
```

And "manipulate!" is being flagged by Rails, saying "undefined method 'manipulate!' for #". Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include this line:

```
include CarrierWave::RMagick
```

Or check out this: 
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/RMagick

Comment: It worked! That was what I was missing. Thanks so much.